# Table inside table going past margin

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment, formatting, positioning

**How can I have the `tabularx` inside question 6 to evenly split into 2 and not go past the margins?**
(I am currently using `p{0.25cm}p{7cm}` which is not optimal as I need to manually specify the width)

Sub-questions (not as important):
How can I line up the (a) and (b) from question 5 to the (a) in question 6?
How can I indent the i., ii. and iii. from question 6 so that it does not line up with the (a) and (b)?

Note that the example below works, but the style and formatting isn't optimal (I'm also getting 2 `Underfull \hbox` and 7 `Overfull \hbox` messages).
Also note that I'm very new to LaTeX typesetting (only installed it yesterday!) and will appreciate any feedback on the overall style of the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


% Set page margin to 1 inch on all sides
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

% Required for custom enumeration styles
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{tabularx}


% Increase line height for table
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}


\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{Large}My Title\end{Large}\\
    \end{center}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \setcounter{enumi}{4}

        \item
            The cumulative frequency graph below represents the height (in meters) of 100 people living in London. (Graph omitted)

            \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
                \item
                    Estimate

                    \begin{multicols}{2}
                        \begin{enumerate}[i.]
                            \item the median height
                            \item the 75\textsuperscript{th} percentile of the height
                        \end{enumerate}
                    \end{multicols}

                \item \ldots
            \end{enumerate}

        \item
            Sketch the solid whose region is given by the integral:

            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|X}
                (a) $\int_0^2 \int_0^3 \int_0^4 dz\ dx\ dy$ & (b) $\int_0^3 \int_{x^2}^{9} \int_0^{e^{5^2}} dz\ dy\ dx$\\
                Rewrite the above integral using the orders: & Rewrite the above integral using the orders:\\
                {
                    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.25cm}p{7cm}}
                          i. & $dx\,dy\,dz$\\
                         ii. & $dy\,dx\,dz$\\
                        iii. & Evaluate each of the above 3 integrals using your calculator
                    \end{tabularx}
                }
                &
                {
                    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.25cm}p{7cm}}
                          i. & $dy\,dz\,dx$\\
                         ii. & $dx\,dy\,dz$\\
                        iii. & Evaluate each of the above 3 integrals using your calculator
                    \end{tabularx}
                }\\
            \end{tabularx}

    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

For those who don't want to compile the document, this is what it looks like right now (click for larger version):
[image]

Comment: You have hard-coded `p{7cm}` in your tables. If you replace them by `p{6cm}` the table does no longer overshoot.

Comment: `tabularx` has to have an `X` column so `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.25cm}p{7cm}}` is wrong,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two kinds of solution:

1) all automatic without tables, if the two sides of the `multicols` are of different height, you could use `\columnbreak`, as in points 7. and 8. of my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Set page margin to 1 inch on all sides
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

% Required for custom enumeration styles
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{tabularx}


% Increase line height for table
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{Large}My Title\end{Large}\\
    \end{center}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \setcounter{enumi}{4}
        \item
        The cumulative frequency graph below represents the height (in meters) of 100 people living in London. (Graph omitted)

        \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
            \item
            Estimate

            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \begin{enumerate}[i.]
                    \item the median height
                    \item the 75\textsuperscript{th} percentile of the height
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{multicols}

            \item \ldots
        \end{enumerate}

        \item
        Sketch the solid whose region is given by the integral:
        \begin{multicols}{2}\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
            \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
                \item $\int_0^2 \int_0^3 \int_0^4 dz\ dx\ dy$

                    Rewrite the above integral using the orders:

                    \begin{enumerate}[i.]
                        \item $dx\,dy\,dz$
                        \item $dy\,dx\,dz$
                        \item Evaluate each of the above 3 integrals using your calculator
                    \end{enumerate}
                \item $\int_0^3 \int_{x^2}^{9} \int_0^{e^{5^2}} dz\ dy\ dx$

                    Rewrite the above integral using the orders:

                    \begin{enumerate}[i.]
                        \item $dy\,dz\,dx$
                        \item $dx\,dy\,dz$
                        \item Evaluate each of the above 3 integrals using your calculator
                    \end{enumerate}
            \end{enumerate}

        \end{multicols}
        \item
        In case the first column is longer than the second one:
        \begin{multicols}{2}\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
            \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
                \item in this case the first column has a text longer than the second one
                \columnbreak
                \item blah      
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{multicols}
        \item
        In case the second column is longer than the first one:
        \begin{multicols}{2}\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
            \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
                \item blah blah blah    
                \columnbreak
                \item in this case the second column has a text longer than the first one   
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{multicols}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

2) with customize counters, and tables:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Set page margin to 1 inch on all sides
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

% Required for custom enumeration styles
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{tabularx}
% Increase line height for table
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}

\newcounter{itemalpha}
\newcounter{itemroman}
\newcommand*{\itemalpha}{\stepcounter{itemalpha}(\alph{itemalpha})}
\newcommand*{\resetitemalpha}{\setcounter{itemalpha}{0}}
\newcommand*{\itemroman}{\stepcounter{itemroman}\roman{itemroman}.}
\newcommand*{\resetitemroman}{\setcounter{itemroman}{0}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{Large}My Title\end{Large}\\
    \end{center}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \setcounter{enumi}{4}

        \item
        The cumulative frequency graph below represents the height (in meters) of 100 people living in London. (Graph omitted)

        \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
            \item
            Estimate

            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \begin{enumerate}[i.]
                    \item the median height
                    \item the 75\textsuperscript{th} percentile of the height
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{multicols}

            \item \ldots
        \end{enumerate}

        \item
        Sketch the solid whose region is given by the integral:

        \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{\hspace{\labelsep}}p{.41\textwidth}|r@{\hspace{\labelsep}}p{.41\textwidth}@{}}
            \itemalpha &$\int_0^2 \int_0^3 \int_0^4 dz\ dx\ dy$ & \itemalpha &$\int_0^3 \int_{x^2}^{9} \int_0^{e^{5^2}} dz\ dy\ dx$\\
            &Rewrite the above integral using the orders: & & Rewrite the above integral using the orders:\\
            &
            {
                \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{\hspace{\labelsep}}p{.37\textwidth}@{}}
                    \itemroman & $dx\,dy\,dz$\\
                    \itemroman & $dy\,dx\,dz$\\
                    \itemroman & Evaluate each of the above 3 integrals using your calculator
                \end{tabular}
            }
            & &
            {
                \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{\hspace{\labelsep}}p{.37\textwidth}@{}}
                    \resetitemroman\itemroman & $dy\,dz\,dx$\\
                    \itemroman & $dx\,dy\,dz$\\
                    \itemroman & Evaluate each of the above 3 integrals using your calculator
                \end{tabular}
            }\\
        \end{tabular}

    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code, in which I have replaced the `p{7cm}` by `X` columns as well as all occurences of `\textwidth` by `\linewidth`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Set page margin to 1 inch on all sides
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

% Required for custom enumeration styles
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{tabularx}


% Increase line height for table
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}


\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{Large}My Title\end{Large}\\
    \end{center}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \setcounter{enumi}{4}

        \item
            The cumulative frequency graph below represents the height (in meters) of 100 people living in London. (Graph omitted)

            \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
                \item
                    Estimate

                    \begin{multicols}{2}
                        \begin{enumerate}[i.]
                            \item the median height
                            \item the 75\textsuperscript{th} percentile of the height
                        \end{enumerate}
                    \end{multicols}

                \item \ldots
            \end{enumerate}

        \item
            Sketch the solid whose region is given by the integral:

            \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X|X}
                (a) $\int_0^2 \int_0^3 \int_0^4 dz\ dx\ dy$ & (b) $\int_0^3 \int_{x^2}^{9} \int_0^{e^{5^2}} dz\ dy\ dx$\\
                Rewrite the above integral using the orders: & Rewrite the above integral using the orders:\\
                {
                    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{0.25cm}X}
                          i. & $dx\,dy\,dz$\\
                         ii. & $dy\,dx\,dz$\\
                        iii. & Evaluate each of the above 3 integrals using your calculator
                    \end{tabularx}
                }
                &
                {
                    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{0.25cm}X}
                          i. & $dy\,dz\,dx$\\
                         ii. & $dx\,dy\,dz$\\
                        iii. & Evaluate each of the above 3 integrals using your calculator
                    \end{tabularx}
                }\\

            \end{tabularx}

    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you could use a solution like the following. I have replaced the inner `tabularx` environment by an `enumerate` environment. To set it up correctly, I have additionally replaced the `enumerate` package by the more powerful `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Set page margin to 1 inch on all sides
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

% Required for custom enumeration styles
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{tabularx}


% Increase line height for table
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{Large}My Title\end{Large}\\
    \end{center}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \setcounter{enumi}{4}

        \item
            The cumulative frequency graph below represents the height (in meters) of 100 people living in London. (Graph omitted)

            \begin{enumerate}[label=({\alph*})]
                \item  Estimate

                    \begin{multicols}{2}
                        \begin{enumerate}[label={\roman*}.]
                            \item the median height
                            \item the 75\textsuperscript{th} percentile of the height
                        \end{enumerate}
                    \end{multicols}

                \item \ldots
            \end{enumerate}

        \item
            Sketch the solid whose region is given by the integral:


          \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X|X}
          (a) $\int_0^2 \int_0^3 \int_0^4 dz\ dx\ dy$ & (b) $\int_0^3 \int_{x^2}^{9} \int_0^{e^{5^2}} dz\ dy\ dx$\\
          Rewrite the above integral using the orders: & Rewrite the above integral using the orders:\\
          \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
            \begin{enumerate}[label={\roman*}.,align=left]
                 \item  $dx\,dy\,dz$
                 \item $dy\,dx\,dz$
                 \item Evaluate each of the above 3 integrals using your calculator
                 \end{enumerate} 
                 \end{minipage}&
                 \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\roman*}.,align=left]
                 \item  $dx\,dy\,dz$
                 \item $dy\,dx\,dz$
                 \item Evaluate each of the above 3 integrals using your calculator
                 \end{enumerate}
                 \end{minipage}
            \end{tabularx}       

    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

To indent i., ii. ... you can add the option `leftmargin=1.75cm` to the corresponding `\begin{enumerate}[label={\roman*}.,align=left]` lines.

The following image compares the output of the two above MWEs. On the left: enumerate approac, on the right: nested tables, black lines are caused by the package `showframe`, that I have included to visualize the margins)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution, with some improvements brought by the medium-size commands from `nccmath`, playing with some lengths. The main difference is that I don't nest `tabularx`s inside another `tabularx`, but an `enumerate` (customised with `enumitem`), so as to obtain a (referable) automatic numbering:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}

    % Set page margin to 1 inch on all sides
    \usepackage[margin=1in, showframe]{geometry}

    % Required for custom enumeration styles
    \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{nccmath}
    \newcommand{\mint}{\medint\int}
    % Increase line height for table
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}

        \begin{center}
            \begin{Large}My Title\end{Large}\\
        \end{center}

        \begin{enumerate}
            \setcounter{enumi}{4}

            \item
                The cumulative frequency graph below represents the height (in meters) of 100 people living in London. (Graph omitted)

                \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
                    \item
                        Estimate
                        \begin{multicols}{2}
                            \begin{enumerate}[i., wide = 0pt]
                                \item the median height
                                \item the 75\textsuperscript{th} percentile of the height
                            \end{enumerate}
                        \end{multicols}
                    \item \ldots
                \end{enumerate}

            \item
                Sketch the solid whose region is given by the integral:

     \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\compress}X|>{\compress}X}
                    (a) $\mint_0^2 \mint_0^3 \mint_0^4 dz\, dx\, dy$ & (b) $\mint_0^3 \mint_{x^2}^{9} \mint_0^{e^{5^2}} dz\, dy\, dx$\\
                    Rewrite the above integral using the orders: & Rewrite the above integral using the orders:\\[-1.5ex]
\begin{enumerate}[i., leftmargin = *, nosep]
  \item $dx\,dy\,dz$
  \item $dx\,dy\,dz$
    \item Evaluate each of the above 3 integrals using your calculator
\end{enumerate}
                    &
\begin{enumerate}[i., leftmargin = *, nosep]
  \item $dx\,dy\,dz$
  \item $dx\,dy\,dz$
    \item Evaluate each of the above 3 integrals using your calculator
\end{enumerate}
\\
                \end{tabularx}
        \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

[image]